# How many domains can be bound with one SSL certificate?

Tags: iis, ssl, asp.net, azure

Let say I have an ASP.NEt application which is bound with more than 10 domains using host headers. Is one certificate is enough for me? or I need more than 1 certificate for each domain?  If I need 1 certificate, then adding a new domain means reinstall the certificate?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are multiple certificate types.

- You can have a wildcard cert `*.domain.com` which is valid for all *subdomains*.
- You can have a single-name cert `host.domain.com` which is only valid for this *host*
- You can have a multi-name cert `host1.domain1.com`, `host2.domain2.com`, this is called a *SAN* (Subject Alternative Name) Certficiate. They are often called *"UC-Certificate"* by cert vendors.

I'm not sure where the technical limit is on a SAN cert, but it's certainly more than 10 names.

Comment: Just see the below comment.

Comment: On many cert vendors, you can add and remove SAN entries anytime, and re-issue the cert. This is however vendor specific.

Comment: Is I need to reinstall the certificate? I mean I need to configure my server every time when I add a new domain.

Comment: Yes, with a SAN Certificate you have to. The only time where you don't have to would be a wildcard cert. Or maybe the SAN cert allows to use Wildcard, to cover multiple domains, not sure (i.e. `*.domain1.com` & `*.domain2.com`

Answer (score 7):

If they are truely unique domain names, you can get a SAN (Subject Alternative Name) certificate. Most vendors will let you put about 40 domain names on one cert. If they are sub-domains, a wildcard cert is the way to go. For each of tjose options you only need 1 ip as the cert is valid for all listed domain names.

Comment: What if I needed to add a new domain in SAN? Is I need to reinstall this domain to server? Whether domain be added dynamically?

Comment: You will need to have the issuer re-issue the cert with the new name in addition to the ones already set up. Most vendors allow you to do this via a web portal. Then you'll need to re-install the cert

Comment: Is I need to configure the server when I add a new domain in SAN certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Typical limit by most issuers are **100 SANs** (inclusive). Wildcard is naturally unlimited.